# Migrating MySQL databases to a new server with phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, migration, phpmyadmin, macos

Looking for the best way to migrate a dozen or so MySQL databases from an old Mac mini to a new one.
I've tried the source machine's phpMyAdmin (v. 4) EXPORT command, using what looked like reasonable options, and with all my existing databases selected. It created a 5+GB SQL file. Scanning through it, I see the "CREATE TABLE" commands but not any "CREATE DATABASE" commands.
Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL docs have explicit instructions for using `mysqladmin` and `mysqldump` to copy a database to another server. If all goes well it's a 2-line operation; better than trying to use `phpMyAdmin`.
Took me a few tries to get server access permissions and user accounts/passwords sorted out, but eventually it worked.
Oddly, I had problems with "server access denied" errors, and what *appeared* to fix them was erasing and retyping the user names in the (copied) command line, plus making sure the cursor was at the end of the command line before executing it. No idea what that's about.

Answer (score -1):

Thats how it is. All mine are the same. It allows you to import the tables (and data) into a different database.

If you are doing it once then its fine. This process is not recommended for large databases, because it becomes slower and bulkier.

Comment: Reading the MySQL docs, seems like `mysqldump` could be the way to go.